# What's the correct method for using Traits and Namespaces for CakePHP 2?

Tags: php, cakephp, namespaces, traits

I'm using CakePHP 2.4.5 and PHP 5.5, and would like to use a trait.

I have a trait in Utility/VariablesTrait.php called `VariablesTrait`.

To take advantage of namespaces, I've given it a namespace of `App\Utility\VariablesTrait`, since `Utility\VariablesTrait` seems a bit too global, and the former would work better with CakePHP 3.

In my class that I want to use it in, I have the `use App\Utility\VariablesTrait;` statement in the class.  For backup, I also have a `App::uses('VariablesTrait', 'Utility');` statement at the top of the file.  I'm not sure if the SPL autoloader is used when looking for traits, which is why I was going for namespaces in the first place.

The small issue is that the app directory is `app`, and since directory structures should match namespaces (I think), I renamed it to `App`.  However, CakeRequest::_base() hardcodes `app`, so determining the controller doesn't work so well.

So, I'm trying to determine if that's a CakePHP bug, or if there is a more appropriate way of using traits in CakePHP 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to do this is to use CakePHP [build](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#add-new-packages-to-an-application) to add your package folder, then just refer to it by the name you chose so for example:

Add this to `bootstrap.php`:

```
/**
 * Add New Package Locations
 */
App::build(['Controller/Trait' => [APP . 'Controller' . DS . 'Trait' . DS]], App::REGISTER);
```

Then just use this to pull in your traits:

```
App::uses('TestTrait', 'Controller/Trait');
```

You can also add multiple package folders at a time so you can apparently do something like this:

```
/**
 * Add New Package Locations
 */
App::build(['All/Trait' => [
    APP . 'Controller' . DS . 'Trait' . DS,
    APP . 'Model' . DS . 'Trait' . DS,
    APP . 'Lib' . DS . 'Trait' . DS
]], App::REGISTER);
```

Comment: Hi, not valid use word from PHP in namespace. Example : namespace Project\Classes\Function; // Causes parse errors  
namespace Project\Abstract\Factory; // Causes parse errors  namespace App\Model\Entity\Trait\; // Causes parse errors  Valid for example is App\Model\Entity\AllTrait\

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that CakePHP doesn't autoload. I use the following for importing namespaced classes:

```
spl_autoload_register(
function ( $class )
{
    foreach ( App::path('Vendor', 'MyFile') as $base )
    {
        $path = $base . str_replace('\\', DS, $class) . '.php';
        if ( file_exists($path) )
        {
            return include $path;
        }
    }
}
);
```