# CakePhp 2.6 How to extend CakeRequest

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.6

I'm trying to extend CakeRequest object to add a couple helper functions so I can make calls similar to how Laravel does it:

Laravel

```
$request->only('username', 'password');
```

CakePHP 2.6

```
$this->request->only('username', 'password');
```

The only two examples I've found are these: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21394852/whats-the-correct-method-for-using-traits-and-namespaces-for-cakephp-2) [2](http://www.programering.com/a/MjNwkjMwATA.html)

But I don't understand how this actually is working, and `app/Config/bootstrap.php` doesn't have `require APP . 'Lib' . DS . 'Network' . DS . 'CakeRequest.php';` for me to override with `require APP . 'Lib' . DS . 'Network' . DS . 'AppCakeRequest.php';` as they suggest.

How do you extend the functionality of CakeRequest in CakePHP 2.6?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29408489/cakephp-3-x-how-to-extend-the-request-class It's pretty much the same in 2.x

Comment: Hi @ndm, I've updated my answer, but it doesn't seem to work.  I started looking at the CakePHP 2.6.x repo (https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.6.12/app/webroot/index.php), but it has a lot more in the index.php than is present in our index.php page.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi @ndm, got it working.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that wants more of a code example refer to the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.6.12/app/webroot/index.php) (bottom of the page), otherwise this is almost verbatum.  Thanks to @ndm for his comments on how to apply the solution.

```
App::uses('Dispatcher', 'Routing');
App::uses('AppCakeRequest', 'Lib/Network');

$Dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
$Dispatcher->dispatch(
    //new CakeRequest(),
    new AppCakeRequest(),
    new CakeResponse()
);
```